# Sharepoint to Report Builder 3.0 empty field

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am building a report using Report Builder 3. I am pulling data from a Sharepoint list. One of the columns is an integer and the value will either be empty, 1 or 0.

When I am working with the data in Report Builder, the empty fields are being handled as if they are zero.

I'm trying to create a graph that shows how many zeros are in the data set and the data is very skewed because it's counting the empty fields as well.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!GreetingPerformed.Value = 0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by testing the length:

```
=Sum(iif(len(Fields!GreetingPerformed.Value ) =0,0,iif(Fields!GreetingPerformed.Value )))
```